# Error 400 Bad Request Ajax JQuery to Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I'm facing am error 400 when trying to post a form data to Spring Controller, I tried some posts here, but nothing worked with form data, I used the same pattern I used in others ajax posts, but some is using @ModelAtributte, and in this case I needed to load two ModelAndView, wich I don't know

the serialized form I get is:

```
idModelo=11&carroRetirada=1&quantidadeMax=78&quantidadeRetirada=1
```

The Ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/catalog/add-modelosemuso',
            data: $('#form-retirada').serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            async: false


        }).success(function () {
            console.log("sent");
            $('#container-modelo-list').load('/catalog/list-modelo');
        })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("Server failed");
            })
            .always(function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("processing ajax...");
                console.log(xhr, status,error);
                console.log($('#form-retirada').serialize());

            });
```

And the Controller is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/catalog/add-modelosemuso",
                    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String addModeloEmUso(@RequestParam("carroRetirada")
                          Integer carroRetiadaId,
                          @RequestParam("quantidadeReitada")
                          Integer quantidadeRetirada,
                          @RequestParam("quantidadeMax")
                          Integer quantidadeMax,
                          @RequestParam("idModelo")
                          Integer idModelo)
    {
        int restante = quantidadeMax - quantidadeRetirada;

        Carros carro = new Carros();
        carro.setIdCarro(carroRetiadaId);

        ModeloPeca modelo = new ModeloPeca();
        modelo.setIdPeca(idModelo);
        modelo.setQuantidade(restante);

        ModelosEmUso modelosEmUso = new ModelosEmUso();
        modelosEmUso.setQuantidadeUsada(quantidadeRetirada);
        modelosEmUso.setCarrosByCarrosIdCarro(carro);
        modelosEmUso.setModelopecaByModeloPecaIdPeca(modelo);

        modeloRepository.save(modelo);
        modelosEmUsoRepository.save(modelosEmUso);
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP request doesn't have the required HTTP parameter called `quantidadeReitada`, the most similar that's present is `quantidadeRetirada` (i.e. *retirada* instead of *reitada*, whatever these mean). Remember to match up all AJAX request parameters with values of `RequestParam`.

Comment: Thanks kryger, was a distraction error, and by the way, _retirada_ in portuguese means  _withdrawal_ in english ;)